I cant install libraries on python
I recently tried installing pygame library on my pc(windows). It didnt worked, ive tried every single possible commands in cmd but still it couldnt make it. Now i tried installing firebase admin library.
It also didnt worked, do you have any ideas how could i fix it? I keep getting infos like this:
   distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
    [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
I tried every single possible command to see if it was badly wrote etc. but it wasnt.

which windows version are you using ?

I use win10 pro

Are you running pip directly (pip.exe) or as a python module (python.exe -m pip . . . ) ? I think it could help people answer if you added the command you used to the question.

I tried both:  pip install firebase-admin, py -m pip install firebase-admin

pygame might be a simpler example to go with if you are just trying to work out why you can't install packages with pip... What is the output when you try to install pygame?

try to work with virtual env not the system on e
